# Using TGlowEffect on a TLabel in Delphi/C++ Builder

Tags: c++, delphi, c++builder, firemonkey

This is a pretty easily explained problem, I'm using FireMonkey to design a form and when I add a TGlowEffect to a tag it ruins the way the Label looks.

If somebody knows how to do this correctly I would appreciate it.

[image]

After applying the TGlowEffect:

[image]

The text is significantly bolded, and the only affect applied was the blur.

**The text only appears like this in the editor, but I would rather it look like it's going to look after I compile.**

Maybe I'm just new to FireMonkey and I'm doing something wrong, if anybody has any good reference material on how to work with FireMonkey correctly I would appreciate a link to that also.

Comment: Submit a QC report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have not already done so, you should apply update 4 (be prepared for fuzzy fonts though) as I have attempted to reproduce this issue without success with my XE2 (updated to 4).  Some more information on what you are actually doing would be useful :-)

As a general thought, rather than adding a glow effect to a label or to a text object, you should change the component style to add a glow effect - this way you can easily apply the same style to other text or labels.